# What's the difference between single quotation and double quotation in GitHub search GUI

Tags: github, search, syntax

I found GitHub GUI returns different searching results by simply changing the quotation of the keywords from single to double.

In GitHub homepage textbox:

- if I put a string like: `org:apache is:pr closed:<2019-02-01 "regular expression" in:title,body`, it returns 115 issues.
- But if the string is `org:apache is:pr closed:<2019-02-01 'regular expression' in:title,body`, I got 125 issues.

I am wondering why it is different since I am expecting the searching results to be the same.

Answer (score 2):

Only double quotes will limit the search to the exact string "`regular expression`"

The second form (single quotes) would allow result with either `regular` or `expression` in it.